# is this correct? $\frac{R}{j\omega L + \frac{1}{j\omega C}}=-j\left(\frac{R}{\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}}\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I wonder if this is correct:

$$\frac{R}{j\omega L + \frac{1}{j\omega C}}=-j\left(\frac{R}{\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}}\right)$$

I figured this middle step, but it has been a while since I last did this sort of thing:

$$\frac{R}{j\omega L + \frac{1}{j\omega C}}= \frac{R}{j\omega L - j \frac{1}{\omega C}} =-j\left(\frac{R}{\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}}\right)$$

Comment: Yep, that's completely correct.

Comment: What do you denote $j$?

Comment: in electrical engineering we use j instead of i because is used for current.